# How to get global access to enum types in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, global-variables

This is probably a stupid question, but I can't seem to do it.  I want to set up some enums in one class like this:

```
public enum Direction { north, east, south, west };
```

Then have that enum type accessible to all classes so that some other class could for instance have:

```
Direction dir = north;
```

and be able to pass the enum type between classes:

```
public void changeDirection(Direction direction) {
   dir = direction;
}
```

I thought that setting the enum to public would make this automatically possible, but it doesn't seem to be visible outside of the class I declared the enum in.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can do one of two things.

**1-** Move the declaration of the enum outside of the class

Today you probably have something like this

```
public class ClassName
{
  public enum Direction
  {
    north, south, east, west
  }
  // ... Other class members etc.
}
```

Which will change to

```
public class ClassName
{      
  // ... Other class members etc.
}

// Enum declared outside of the class
public enum Direction
{
  north, south, east, west
}
```

**2-** Reference the enum using the class name

```
ClassName.Direction.north
```

Eg.

```
public void changeDirection(ClassName.Direction direction) { 
   dir = direction; 
}
```

Where `ClassName` is the name of the class that you declared the enum in.

Answer (score 19):

Declare enum in the scope of a namespace like a class but not into a class:

```
namespace MyApplication
{
   public enum Direction { north, east, south, west };
}
```

In case enum is declared in the scope of a class, you have make this class public too:

```
namespace MyApplication
{
   public class MyClass
   {
      public enum Direction { north, east, south, west };
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
MyClass.Direction dir = ...
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? - abatishchev's answer explains it all very clearly.

Answer (score 5):

It's public, but defining an enum inside a class makes it an inner type of that class. For instance:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public enum MyEnum { One, Two, Three }
    }
}
```

In order to access this enum from another class in the `MyNamespace` namespace, you have to reference it as `Foo.MyEnum`, not just `MyEnum`. If you want to reference it as simply `MyEnum`, declare it just inside the namespace rather than inside the class:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Foo { ... }

    public enum MyEnum { One, Two, Three }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `enum` definition inside of the `Program.cs` file, but outside of the `Program` class. This will make the `enum` type globally accessible without having to reference the class name.

```
namespace YourApp
{    
    enum Direction { north, east, south, west };

    static class Program
    {   
    }
}
```

Then you can access it **anywhere** in **any** class within the same namespace without the need to specify the class name like this:

```
Direction d;
d = Direction.north;
```