# How can I make a switch statement work with an enum? C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

**Description**

I'm working on a script to fade UI elements in Unity, similar to a selector, where you can select the type of fading, and duration, and image to fade

[image]

I found that enum is the best option to achieve that result, but I have a problem, when I run the code only element of the enum work and the other don't, no matter if I use `switch`or `if` just the first statement run, I don't know what's wrong with the code

- Please explain your answer
- Please explain why the code is wrong
- Please give feedback on how to improve

I'm using Unity version 5.3.5f1 and Visual Studio Community 2015

**Goal**

- Make the enum work properly using either `switch` or `if`
- Be able to use the variables inside the FadeOperations class to make
  the calculations inside the Test class
- Select from an array the type of desired operation
- Select an UI element from Heriarchy and fade it

**Steps**

- Create new Unity project (2D or 3D)
- Create UI Image
- Create Empty game object
- Create new C# script (I called it Test)
- Attach new script to empty game object

**Code**

Here's my code...

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

 public enum FadeManager
 {
     fadeIn,
     fadeOut
 };

 [System.Serializable]
 public class FadeOperations
 {
     [Tooltip("Type of fading")]
     public FadeManager fadeType;

     [Tooltip("Duration time of the fading")]
     public float duration;

     [Tooltip("Select the image to fade")]
     public Image fadeImage;
 }

 public class Test : MonoBehaviour
 {
     [Tooltip("Select your type of fade")]
     public FadeOperations[] fadeOperations;

     //Reference to the class FadeOperations
     private FadeOperations _fo = new FadeOperations();

     //Loop for debug
     private void Start()
     {
         Debug.Log(_fo.fadeType);
         switch (_fo.fadeType)
         {
             //This statement works
             case FadeManager.fadeIn:
                 Debug.Log("Fadein"); //Only this piece of code works
                 break;

             //This statement doesn't work
             case FadeManager.fadeOut:
                 Debug.Log("Fadeout");
                 break;
         }
      }
  }
```

The result of the Log `(_fo.fadeType)` before the `switch`

```
fadeIn
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Test:Start() (at Assets/_Scripts/Test.cs:34)
```

Comment: You don´t assign `_fo.fadeType` a value so it gets its default-value which usually is the very first value of the enum. Furthermore your question is quite unclear. The topic seems to be homework, however you should only post those parts you have problems with, not the whole task.

Comment: could you explain more?

Comment: You have to set a value for `_fo.fadeType`, you can´t expect your application to simply provide any arbitrary value for it. If you don´t do the object simply gets its first value as enumerations can´t be `null`.

Comment: I see... so... how can I improve the code?

Comment: We can´t say you how to set this value, you have to know self. Obviously you need some basics of programming first, what a `switch` does and how instances of classes are created, in particular how `enum`s are treated. Basically it comes down to you creating an instance of `FadeOperations` using `new FadeOperations()`. However you never change any of it´s properties - be it `fadeType`, `duration`or `fadeImage`. You have to set thopse explicitely or the compiler will use default-values for them - the first enum-value for example.

Comment: I was hoping someone could explain my mistakes and help me improve (with or without programming knowledge)... thanks anyway

Comment: something like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844899/how-to-get-global-access-to-enum-types-in-c)... maybe

Comment: For this we have to know what exactly you want to do. Currently there´s just a few questions - probably from a homework - and some code and we should determine which parts of the questions the code handles and how to improve it to match your questions. However this is *your* turn and no-one on SO is doing what you´re supposed to do. You should ask a specific question. This usually includes some code and where exactly you´re stuck and what you expect. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get more help on your problem

Comment: Aren't you basing your decisions on the `_fo` FadeOperation, while what you publicly set in your inspector is a value of an element in the `fadeOperations` array. You can set those elements to anything, but your case statement won't pick that up and therefore logs what it shows you.

Comment: is there a way to improve the code? if so, how? what would you suggest?

Comment: I don't really know what you want to improve. If you're changing the values in the array, use them to check your case statements, and not `_fo`.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you need to do something like `_fo.FadeType = someFadeType`. This obviously needs to involve some sort of logic, conditions. E.g. when you load a scene (= fadeIn) and when you exit a scene (= FadeOut).

Answer (score 2):

Here is something you may want to do:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Tooltip("Select your type of fade")]
    public FadeOperations[] fadeOperations;

    //Loop for debug X  NOTE: Start method runs only one time.dont expect it to run it for multiple time 
    private void Start()
    {
        foreach(var operation in fadeOperations)
        {
            Debug.Log(operation.fadeType);
            switch (operation.fadeType)
            {
                case FadeManager.fadeIn:
                    Debug.Log("Fadein"); // write your fading in code here
                    break;

                case FadeManager.fadeOut:
                    Debug.Log("Fadeout"); // write your fading out code here
                    break;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Correct -- BTW just use "Header" rather than "Tooltip" - it's cooler  :)